# How to keep the mouse within the borders [Dual monitors]

Tags: battlefield-2, battlefield-2142

When I play these games on any resolution, I can't aim to the right else my cursor goes off screen and clicks on to my other screen.  It minimizes the game and really hinders my ability to play since I can't seem to keep the cursor in the window and it keeps getting me minimized and killed.

Is there a resolution for this issue?  I can't seem to find any settings that prevent the cursor from going out of the border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a piece of software called [DualMonitorTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortool/) (free as in speech) that I've used in the past to do this.  You can bind a hotkey to lock the cursor to the current monitor, and then there won't be any chance of it moving to the other.

Once upon a time when I used nVidia cards, there were options in the advanced settings of the nVidia control panels that allowed you to do something similar.  You might have a look at your graphics card's settings to see if there's some way to bind a hotkey to lock the cursor to a particular monitor.  However, I think these types of things have fallen out of popularity among the card vendors.

I've also seen some AutoHotKey scripts (a useful tool for any PC gaming enthusiast!) that [purport to do something similar](http://www.arcengames.com/forums/index.php?topic=10382.0).  I haven't checked them out, but they might be worth a look.  AutoHotKey scripts can activate/deactivate based on the active window, so that might remove the need to use a macro to start/stop the monitor lock.

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look at my graphics card settings then if that fails, I'll check out your first link.  Thanks!